# How to Hide past and next month date in flutter tablecalendar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I used the flutter [TableCalendar plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar), I want to Hide the past and next month date options. my code is. [image: example this]

```
             child: TableCalendar(
                  headerVisible: false,
                  daysOfWeekVisible: false,
                  focusedDay: selectedDay,
                  firstDay: DateTime.now(),
                  lastDay: DateTime(2050),
                  startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
                  availableGestures: AvailableGestures.none,
                  daysOfWeekHeight: 20,
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official example: https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/events_example.dart

```dart
TableCalendar(
  calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
    outsideDaysVisible: false,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there are properties firstDay and lastDay. So, you can assign values to that properties as below.

Code:

```
child: TableCalendar(
                  headerVisible: false,
                  daysOfWeekVisible: false,
                  focusedDay: selectedDay,
                  firstDay: DateTime.now(),
                  lastDay: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, now.month + 1, 0).day, // This will return last day of current month
                  startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
                  availableGestures: AvailableGestures.none,
                  daysOfWeekHeight: 20,
            ),
```

So, by using above code the user will not able to access day before current date and day after end of this month. Hope this will help you. If you still have some questions then please comment.

Comment: Not working this method

Comment: What error are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use outsideBuilder:

```
TableCalendar(
...
...
 calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
       outsideBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) => Container(),
 )
)
```